# Tor slow to respond on control port on mobile

Tags: configuration, mobile

We have an application that's trying to connect to Tor, and when Tor starts, it blocks for about 15 seconds before responding on the control port.

This is the behaviour we are observing:

```
Nov 16 13:21:17.969 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:39069
Nov 16 13:21:17.969 [notice] Opened Control listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:39069
Nov 16 12:21:18 starting application
Nov 16 13:21:33.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Nov 16 12:21:33 tor connected
Nov 16 13:21:33.000 [notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
Nov 16 13:21:33.000 [notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
Nov 16 13:21:33.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
```

As soon as Tor has opened its control port, we send the auth cookie to the port but we wait for the ok back from Tor. But this only happens after tor prints `Starting with guard context "default"`

The question is, what is Tor doing between opening the control port and printing that out? It looks like something is blocking Tor. It's not doing the same behaviour on PC.

Is there something we can enable to see better logs and see what Tor is doing and how we can remove that blocker?

After that startup, if Tor is kept open, it will always respond fairly quickly. It's just on the initial startup where something is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

It's bootstrapping :D Check the logs: it has to be up and running so you will have an working instance to control, so that's why it happens after that time. But anyway - it should respond you. So use the protocol to check if it's bootstrapped, if it's not - just give it like 15 seconds before checking again

Comment: How can I check the logs for a more detailed description to what I have now?

But the issue is, I am not getting any response back during that 15 secs, its as if the program hangs for 15 seconds, before it starts bootsraping.

Comment: tor mobile app does have logs displayed - just check the app. As a workaround - it's a localhost connection, so when making a connection - set a custom timeout like 1 second. And - actually - it's a bit odd that it does not respond you fast when not bootstrapped, it should. On some Android builds such problems can be caused by battery saver, so check without it when on a charging wire

Comment: well, that's the problem I want to solve, why does not respond? It's as if the tor process freezes for a while.

Comment: what are your hardware and your Android version?

Comment: iPhone XS, iOS 17.1.1

Comment: Apple is vile to anonymity tools and VPN, but I tried it on 8+ and it was flawless - UNLESS the phone was in energy saving mode